# Send filename from JS code to a Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('file').value;
if (fullPath) {
   var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
   var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
   if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
     filename = filename.substring(1);
   }
}
if(passAll === true){
  alert(filename);
}
```

As the title sugests, how can I send that `var filename` to a `view history` (just print it there) obviously after testing that last `if`? My view is empty so it is free for edit. Another question is if the names are going to be saved or discarded after dropping the server?

And here is my controller `history_controller.rb`:

```
class HistoryController < ApplicationController
    def historico
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you checkout Ajax? You can communicate between client and server

Comment: How does it work? I've seen a lot of things with ajax but I never really understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rails routes` in the command line of your project directory. Assuming that `HistoryController` is in `routes.rb`, it will show the routes available to send or request data from your controller.  It should some something like 
`POST   /history      history#create`. That means you can send your filename via an HTTP POST request `{RAILS ROOT URL}/history?filename={THE FILENAME}` (if you are developing locally, it will probably be something like `http://localhost:3000/history?filename={THE FILENAME}`. Then you can access the filename in the `create` action of your `HistoryController` with the syntax `params[:filename]`.

Comment: All I have is `historico_path | GET | app/views/history/historico | history#historico` and it is working so... I dont know. There should be something else?